# Should I use Weighted Average vs Arithmetic Average in my data?

Tags: statistics, average, weighted-average

Should I use weighted average vs arithmetic average in my data?

Columns(Month, Bookings, Day, Bookings/Day)

Should I do Bookings/Days OR Avg(Bookings/day) to get average by month?

Comment: We cannot answer this, as there is no correct answer here; talk to customers and see what the consensus is, and/or offer a switch somewhere to choose between the two methods.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about statistics and not programming or coding.

Answer (score 0):

You have to take Weighted Average for getting average by month 
[sumof(Day's*Bookings)]/Month